# "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when using parameters in code

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, parameters

I am fairly new to PowerShell and I am currently writing a script that does a backup of SharePoint list items. The output format is an excel file. I have one method in my module that accepts 3 parameters: the SharePoint Site URL, the List's name and the path where the excel file should be saved.

So I call this method from a test script and pass along the parameters. But I get an error when I try to instantiate both the Site and the List objects.

Here is my module:

```
Function Export-SPListToExcel($siteURL, $listname, $FolderToSaveTo)
{     
    Import-Modules

    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)

    $web = $site.OpenWeb()

    $list = $web.Lists[$listname.ToString()]

    $table = $list.Items.GetDataTable()

    $Path = $FolderToSaveTo + (Get-Date).ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace(":","").Replace(".","") + ".xlsx"

    $table | Export-XLSX -Path $Path -ClearSheet    
}

Function Import-Modules
{
    if(-Not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "PSExcel"))
    {        
        $psd = (Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath) + "\PSExcel\PSExcel.psd1"
        $psm = (Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath) + "\PSExcel\PSExcel.psm1"
        Import-Module $psd
        Import-Module $psm
    }

    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
    {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
    }
}
```

And here is my test script:

```
if(-Not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "SaveAsExcel"))
{
    Import-Module C:\Temp\PSExcel-master\PSExcel-master\SaveAsExcel.psm1 
}

$path = "C:\Temp\"
$url = "http://sp2013dev3:85/sites/wtpersonal"
$list = "Activities"

Export-SPListToExcel($url, $list, $path)
```

The error happens at this line:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)
```

and this line

```
$list = $web.Lists[$listname.ToString()]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: if I hard-code my parameters into the module, it works.

Comment: Try `Export-SPListToExcel $url  $list $path`. In PoweShell you don't use commas and brackets for parameters.

Comment: thanks! that did it! do you know why my method didn't work? if you want, you can add an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Just accept Ansgar's answer. It even explains why :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell comma-separated parameter lists in parentheses are only used in method calls:

```
$object.SomeMethod('foo', 'bar')
```

In function calls you pass arguments as a space-separated list:

```
Invoke-Function 'foo' 'bar'
                     ^
                no comma here
```

That's because in PowerShell comma and parentheses have special meanings. The comma separates the elements of an array, so

```
Invoke-Function 'foo', 'bar'
```

would pass an array with the 2 elements `'foo'` and `'bar'` to the first parameter of the function.

Parentheses are used for evaluating expressions inside other expressions:

```
$i = 1
Invoke-Function ('{0:d2}' -f $i)
```

The above creates a double-digit string `"01"` from the integer value `$i` and passes that to the first parameter of the function.